# My program generates ten random multiplication questions.After each,tells whether user got the right answer or wrong and displays the correct answer

Tags: python-3.x

My Sample code so far looks like this. I am using IDLE version 3.8 of python.

```
import random
Question1 = '3 * 5'
Question2 = '4 * 8'
Question3 = '3 * 4'
Question4 = '2 * 3'
Question5 = '5 * 5'
Question6 = '7 * 7'
Question7 = '8 * 5'
Question8 = '9 * 8'
Question9 = '2 * 7'
Question10 = '10 * 8'
Answer1 = 15
Answer2 = 32
Answer3 = 12
Answer4 = 6
Answer5 = 25
Answer6 = 49
Answer7 = 40
Answer8 = 72
Answer9 = 14
Answer10 = 80
questions = [Question1,Question2,Question3,Question4,Question5,Question6,Question7,Question8,Question9,Question10]
random.shuffle(questions)
if questions[0] == Question1:
    print(Question1)
    user_input = eval(input('The answer is: '))
    if user_input == Answer1:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('false')
        print('The correct answer is:',Answer1)
if questions[0] == Question2:
    print(Question2)
    user_input = eval(input('The answer is: '))
    if user_input == Answer2:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('false')
        print('The correct answer is:',Answer2)
if questions[0] == Question3:
    print(Question3)
    user_input = eval(input('The answer is: '))
    if user_input == Answer3:
        print('True')
    else:
        print('false')
        print('The correct answer is:',Answer3)
```

The output is not displaying all the ten random questions at once. Instead, I had to compile IDLE after each question to get a new random question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is way to over complicated. you need to think more progromatically about how to approach such problems. The below example will ask how many questions to be answered, it will then generate that many random questions and track if the user answered right or wrong

```py
from random import randint

num_questions = int(input("How many questions do you want to answer: "))
questions = [(randint(1,10), randint(1,10)) for _ in range(num_questions)]
results = []
for index, question in enumerate(questions):
    user_answer = int(input(f"Question {index + 1} - What is {question[0]} x {question[1]}: "))
    real_answer = question[0] * question[1]
    if user_answer == real_answer:
        print("Correct")
        results.append(True)
    else:
        print(f"Incorrect, the answer is {real_answer}")
        results.append(False)

total = len(results)
correct = len([result for result in results if result])
incorrect = len([result for result in results if not result])
percentage = correct / total * 100
print('###Results Summary###')
print(f'Correct answers: {correct}')
print(f'Incorrect answers: {incorrect}')
print(f'result percentage: {percentage:0.2f}')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
How many questions do you want to answer: 3
Question 1 - What is 7 x 2: 14
Correct
Question 2 - What is 6 x 3: 15
Incorrect, the answer is 18
Question 3 - What is 1 x 6: 6
Correct
###Results Summary###
Correct answers: 2
Incorrect answers: 1
result percentage: 66.67
```

Comment: Thanks. I am just a beginner in Python.

Comment: If you find your self writting the same bits of code again and again then chances are there is a better way to do it.